# Windows 10 IOT 14393 SDK Windows.Devices.Gpio bug

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10-universal, windows-10-iot-core

I have a problem with the new "Windows IOT Extensions for UWP" reference from Windows 10 14393 SDK (Anniversary Update)

I have a code that use the Windows.Devices.Gpio namespace (Windows IOT Extensions for UWP). Since i've updated the reference to the 14393 one, the namespace Windows.Devices.Gpio will not be founded anymore by Visual Studio.

If I switch the reference to the 10586 one, I have the same issue... With the 10240 it's build.

If I deploy this builded package to my Raspberry Pi (14939); the software crash without any breakpoint hit with this error : **Exception thrown: 'System.TypeLoadException' in mscorlib.ni.dll**. If I remove all call to the Windows.Devices.Gpio namespace; the breakpoint hits back.

Environnement:

- Pc: Windows 10 Family 14393
- Visual Studio 2015 Community Update 3 english (all up to date)
- Raspberrpi 2B fresh install on 14393

=> Visual Studio repair done. No change.

=> On my computer the C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Extension SDKs\WindowsIoT\10.0.14393.0\ don't reference Windows.Devices.Gpio in any file.

=> The SDK install is currently not working https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive

Bug for me? Bug for everybody?

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: The MSDN docs for GpioController suggest that in version 10.0.14393.0 it is no longer exclusive to IoT but now available in Universal.  Ensure you are referencing the contract, should be Windows.Devices.DevicesLowLevelContract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally resolved this issue .

The "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\Windows.Devices.DevicesLowLevelContract\2.0.0.0" folder didn't have the "Windows.Devices.DevicesLowLevelContract.winmd" file. (bug in installation maybe)

So i've : 
- uninstalled the SDK 14393. 
- Delete the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\Windows.Devices.DevicesLowLevelContract\2.0.0.0" folder. 
- reinstalled the SDL 14393 (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive)

=> The winmd file was created.

In Visual Studio i've added (in the Package.appxmanifest) :

In 14393 it's not necessary anymore to reference the IOT Extension.

Thanks Hans Passant for help

Comment: Yeap, you don't need to reference IoT Extension in order to use GpioController in 14393.

Comment: One more thing to watch out is you need to make sure your Target version is 14393 when referencing the 14393 IoT Extension.